# Is it possible to use private email sending domains as a cloud page domain?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, custom-domain

At the moment, the customer only has a single URL available for creating the cloudpage, he was informed by a salesforce ticket that it is possible to register the private domains that are used for sending emails as a cloudpage access domain, but looking for official documentation I didn't find any information that confirms this, could you let me know if this is possible, and if so how could I be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on whether your customer has purchased that sender domain as part of a Sender Authentication Package (SAP), or as a Private Domain.

SAP already includes a Private Domain for Cloud Pages:

> - Account Branding - Marketing Cloud brands your account with your chosen authenticated custom domain. This feature modifies
>   view-as-a-webpage, link and image wrapping, and removes all references
>   to Marketing Cloud in favor of your custom authenticated domain.
> - Private Domain for Email sending - This feature assigns a domain used to send email. This domain acts as the From address for your
>   email sends. Salesforce Marketing Cloud authenticates your email sends
>   using the Sender Policy Framework (SPF), Sender ID, and
>   DomainKeys/DKIM authentication.
> - Custom Domain for CloudPages - This feature includes a private domain for CloudPages.
> - Dedicated IP Address - This feature assigns a unique IP address to your account. All email messages sent from your account from Marketing
>   Cloud use this IP address. This IP address represents most of your
>   sending reputation.
> - Reply Mail Management - This feature controls the replies you receive from your subscribers. You can assign filters for
>   out-of-office messages and manual unsubscribe requests.

So if your customer doesn't already have it configured, they should just raise a support ticket asking it to be enabled. There can be cases (e.g. they only purchased a Private Domain for sender domain) where they will need to purchase an additional Private Domain SKU before being able to ask for the Cloud Page domain to be configured.

But there is nothing on Marketing Cloud side preventing them from using same domain for sends as well as for Cloud Pages. Be aware however, that the Cloud Page domain will prepend "cloud." to the sender domain. So if they are sending from marketing.example.com, their Cloud Pages will be available at https://cloud.marketing.example.com

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

at the moment they have 5 Additional Private Domains registered in Authenticated Domains and 1 Sender Authentication Domain

They are looking to use these 5 Additional Private Domains as usable URL links for cloudpage

I did not find in any documentation a configuration that accomplishes this, only information that new domains must be acquired only by the SAP service package

i'm quite confused how salesforce support confirmed the possibility of this setup with them

Comment: You don't need to purchase an SAP to use a Private Domain as a Cloud Page domain. Since you can only have a single SAP per Business Unit, you will not be able to utilize multiple sender domains there. Your customer can purchase (if not already done) multiple Private Domains, and use them for Cloud Pages. Support should be able to confirm, whether there are any available Private Domain SKUs in the contract, allowing for configuring these domains as Cloud Page domains. If not, your customer will need to purchase more Private Domain SKUs by reaching out to the Account Executive from Salesforce

Comment: thank you for the informations